# How to make emacs prompt yes or no to save the session when desktop-save-mode is on?

Tags: desktop, session, quitting

I started to use emacs a few days ago and still getting the hang of it.

desktop-save-mode is really handy at times as I don't have to reopen all the files that I had already opened in my previous session. But, I wouldn't want emacs to remember the open buffers every time I quit a session. So, is there a way to make emacs prompt to ask yes or no to invoke desktop-save-mode before quitting ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4485083/324105 might be of interest (even though this is almost the opposite to what you actually asked for).

With the custom `my-desktop` command, I only load my desktop file when I *want* to do that. Once loaded, I *do* automatically save it (but to my mind, if I loaded a desktop file, why wouldn't I want to save it?)

The point being that if you start Emacs and don't want to load and save your desktop file, then you simply don't call `my-desktop`, and no desktop file is written when you exit.